# how to specify drupal mail save file module's directory path?

Tags: drupal

I have installed above mentioned module.

It works fine, my doubt is how to mention current year in file directory field. Since, I would like to get mails saved in sub directories in format : `year/month/date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your own `hook_file_presave()` function and hook file saving path:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7.x

See what you have in that $file variable passed to the function, try somehow to detect that this module is saving the file and in that case change file path the way you want.